# How can I make table row background color override cell input elements background color?

Tags: html, css

When a user clicks the table row, I apply the following class to the row

```
tr.selected {
background-color:#FFA76C;
}
```

However there are inputs in cells with background colors that is overriding the background color of the row. (For example in the picture attached, the first and third row are selected.  The first row, cells one and three inputs are overriding the row background with yellow.)

[image]

I want the background color of the row to be the predominant color when selected, overriding the color of the table cell inputs inside the row.

```js
function selectRow(row) {
    if (row.className.indexOf("selected") != -1) {
        row.className = row.className.replace("selected", "");
    } else {
        row.className += " selected";
    }
}
```

```css
tr.selected{
    background-color:#FFA76C;
}
```

```html
<table>
<tbody>
  <tr class="selected"  style="height: 20px;">
  <th align="left" style="font-size:11px;border:1px solid grey;padding-bottom: 3px;white-space: nowrap;" onclick="selectRow(this.parentNode);"><div style="width:15px"></div>
  </th>
  <td align="left" style="font-size:11px;border:1px solid grey;height: 20px;overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap;">
  <input type="text" style="border: none; width: 150px; height: 100%; text-align: center; overflow: hidden; background: rgb(255, 255, 0);">
  </td>
  
  <td align="left" style="font-size:11px;border:1px solid grey;height: 100%;overflow: hidden;align: left; white-space: nowrap;"><input type="text" style="border: none;width: 150px;height: 100%;text-align: center;overflow: hidden;background: transparent;"></td>
  
  <td align="left" style="font-size:11px;border:1px solid grey;width: 99%;overflow: hidden;"><input type="text"  style="border: none; width: 100%; height: 100%; text-align: center; overflow: hidden; background: rgb(255, 255, 0);"></td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: We'd need a demo but simple specificity should take care of this but removing the `td` bg with `tr.selected td {background-color:none;}`

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

apply this one

```
tr.selected td {
    background-color:#FFA76C !important;
}
```

to avoid from !important, define this property after the cell property which is overriding this property.

Comment: In your answer change td to input and it works for my case - sorry my original post I thought the cell was colored but it wasn't, it was the input within the cell that was the problem. I updated the post.

Answer (score 4):

try to use something like

```
tr.selected td, tr.selected th {
    background-color: transparent;
}
```

so, the bg color of the `th` or `td` inside the table row will not overwrite the `tr` color.
Also you should use the `!important` to overwrite the inline-styles (or avoid using inline-styles, which is better).